# Isometry Between C[0,1] and C[1,2]

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces, isometry

This is not homework, I am just trying to make something clear for myself.

I am trying to show that $C([0,1])$ and $C([1,2])$ are isometric. Here both spaces are endowed with the standard sup metric. I am stuck on the distance preserving part of this proof. I have already worked out that $f(t)=t+1$ is a bijection between $[0,1]$ and $[1,2].$ I want to claim that $\phi:C([0,1]) \to C([1,2])$ defined $\phi(f)(t)=f(t+1)$ is an isometry. My work so far is:

Direct computation yields that $\phi^{-1}(f)=f(x-1).$ Indeed

$$\phi^{-1}(\phi(f))=\phi^{-1}(f(x+1))=f(x-1+1)=f(x)$$
and

$$\phi(\phi^{-1}(f))=\phi(f(x-1))=f(x+1-1)=f(x)$$

so that $\phi$ is bijective. Now, we know from how we derived the bijection between two closed intervals that the map $t \mapsto t+1$ is a bijection between $[0,1]$ and $[1,2].$ In particular $x \in [0,1]$ if and only if $x+1 \in [1,2].$  This is where I'm stuck. I want to show that

$$\underset{t \in [1,2]}{sup}|\phi(f(t))-\phi(g(t))|=\underset{t \in [0,1]}{sup}|f(t)-g(t)|$$

but the above does not make sense since $\phi(f)(t)=f(t+1)$ cannot take $3$ as an input for example. Is my map just wrong, maybe use $f(x-1)$ or something like that, or am I missing something obvious from a set theoretic perspective? Thank you for the help.

Comment: Take $\phi(f)(t)=f(t-1)$

Comment: Yup that worked! Thank you very much. Is it enough to cite that the map $f(t):[1,2]\to[0,1]$ defined $f(t)=t-1$ is a bijection to justify the needed distance preserving equality?

Comment: Yes, that is enough.

Comment: Great! Thank you so much for the help.